# SQL function on all rows using row parameter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has 3 columns I care about: `Name`, `Id` and `ParentId`. I would like to find out how many children an `Id` has which will require me to go through each row.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION numChildren(givenId INT64)
  RETURNS INT64
  AS ((SELECT count(*) FROM `playground.table` WHERE ParentId = givenId));

SELECT numChildren(Id) OVER() as Test FROM `playground.table`
```

The exact error I'm getting is: `Error: Function USER_DEFINED_FUNCTIONS:NUMCHILDREN does not support an OVER clause at [5:8]`.

I want to go through each row, pass the `Id` into the function and then get back the number of rows that have that `Id` as the `ParentId`.

Am I going about this the right way? Would I have to use the APIs to do a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `OVER()` as below

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION numChildren(givenId INT64)
RETURNS INT64
  AS ((SELECT count(*) FROM `playground.table` WHERE ParentId = givenId));

SELECT numChildren(Id) as Test FROM `playground.table`
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. When would I need to use `OVER()` as I thought it's used when you want to execute a query on all rows of a table? Is it because I'm using a function where I am already passing in a field from each row of the table?